# How to Post a runnable to a View that invalidates the View sometimes doesn't work

Tags: asp.net

I been fighting an odd issue these last few days. I have a custom ExpandableListAdapter where each row contains an ImageView, among other things. I have a class that handles the asynchronous loading of images from the multitude of places they may reside (disk cache, app data, remote server, etc). In my adapter's getView method I delegate the responsibility of returning a View to the list Item itself (I have multiple row types for my group list). I request the image load as follows:

final ImageView thumb = holder.thumb;

holder.token = mFetcher.fetchThumb(mImage.id, new BitmapFetcher.Callback() {

```
        @Override
        public void onBitmap(final Bitmap b) {
            thumb.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    thumb.setImageBitmap(b);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure() {
        }
    });
```